# Use two xsd schemas in visual studio 2012

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2012

I've got a webservice that generates some XML.

```
<Town>
<Countrycode>gb</Countrycode>
<CountryName>United Kingdom</CountryName>
<CleanedAccentCity>Seamill</CleanedAccentCity>
<RegionName>North Ayrshire</RegionName>
<Population>0</Population>
<Distance>0.0497417145329766</Distance>
</Town>
```

This I added to my Visual Studio 2012 project by Add New Item... XML to schema.

That works great I wind up with an xsd file in my project then in code I can write:

```
 Public Property returnedXML As XElement
```

..

```
  arr = client.DownloadString("http://host/myservice.asmx/GetTopTownsByLatLon?Latitude=" & p.latitude & "&Longitude=" & p.longitude )

     returnedXML = XElement.Parse(arr)

     firstChild = returnedXML.Descendants().First

     City = firstChild...<City>.Value
      etc..
```

And when I type the .. after firstChild I get intellisense  that shows me the attributes in the XML.

Now what I need to do is get another different webservice to give me some other data.  So I do the same process, and get my XSD files saved into the project.  But, guess what, the intellisense no longer works.

Clearly I need to identify which XSD file needs to be read for the intelisense.  Where do I set that?

Here are the two XSD files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Towns">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Town">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="url" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="Distance" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Towns">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Town">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Countrycode" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="CountryName" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="CleanedAccentCity" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="RegionName" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="Population" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
              <xs:element name="Distance" type="xs:decimal" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are conflicts between these schemes definitions (like duplicated element definitions etc.), the source is not compiled and intellisense not work.

Can you share both XSD files?

EDIT:

Both XSD has a duplicate elements (`<Towns>, <Town> and <Distance>`) and no namespace definitions, so there is no way to difference between theirs. In order to works properly you have two ways:

- First way: Change these name elements in only one of your XSD, for example `<TownsA>, <TownA>, <DistanceA>`:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="TownsA">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="TownA">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="url" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="DistanceA" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  ```

  And keep the second untouched:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Towns">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Town">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Countrycode" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="CountryName" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="CleanedAccentCity" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="RegionName" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="Population" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
                <xs:element name="Distance" type="xs:decimal" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  ```

  - Second way: Add a different targetNamespaceNamespaces in your schemas in `<xs:schema>`:

First XSD:

```
<xs:schema 
       attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
       elementFormDefault="qualified" 
       targetNamespace="http://mynamespace.org/1"
       xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

Second XSD:

```
<xs:schema 
       attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
       elementFormDefault="qualified" 
       targetNamespace="http://mynamespace.org/2"
       xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

Comment: Any one else has the same problem here is a cool video http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb902767.aspx that additionally helps with the `imports` statements at the top.