# VB.net Axis notation not picking up node value

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I have a bit of XML coming down from a webservice

```
<data>
  <request>
    <type>LatLon</type>
    <query>Lat 60.17 and Lon 24.94</query>
  </request>
  <time_zone>
    <localtime>2014-11-30 19:56</localtime>
    <utcOffset>2.0</utcOffset>
  </time_zone>
  <current_condition>
```

I want to pull the local time part into a variable.

Here is the code.

```
Public Function callWorldWeatherOnlineSearch(latitude, longitude) As Boolean


        Using client As New WebClient

            client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8

            Dim arr = client.DownloadString("https://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v2/weather.ashx?q=" & latitude & "%2C" & longitude & "&format=xml&num_of_days=5&tp=24&showlocaltime=yes&key=KEY")

            returnedXML = XElement.Parse(arr)

            localTime = returnedXML...<data>...<time_zone>...<localTime>.Value


        End Using

        Return True
    End Function
```

The localTime variable contains nothing.

Most annoyingly when i write the code in Visual Studio the axis notation correctly (appears to!) walks the XML so I don't know what I am doing wrong?

[image: Axis Notation Prompting]

It does not work if I go straight for the node either..  I'm sure this worked before?  There are no other localTime nodes.

```
   localTime = returnedXML...<localtime>.Value
```

UPDATE:

Here is the code for the class:

[image]

Here is a grab of the .xsd file and targetNamespace unique reference

[image]

Here they are sat next to each other in the solution explorer

[image]

I just noticed that it was localTime so I changed it to localtime, but still to no avail. Check the grab at the assignment line.

[image]

The the next line (where assignment should have occurred).. big fat nothing.

[image]

And here is the locals window:

[image]

Thanks for bearing with me on this.  What else can I check?

UPDATE 2:

So nothing happening here, and I really don't want to get into Xpath.  So I thought I'd try moving the .xsd and weather class into a different folder.

I also removed the imports reference to the xsd, wonder if it would search the local folder first.

Now it is picking up the wrong XSD file.  Is this a clue, does the XSD have to match at runtime, and could there be some problem there.

[image]

UPDATE 3:

OK.  I pulled all this out into a separate project just to home in the problem.

It still didn't work, until I tried removing the reference from the XSD file

I pulled targetNamespace ="http://mynamespace.org/wwo" from the .xsd and congo it works!

So back to my main project.

I removed the targetNamespace ="http://mynamespace.org/wwo" as before and the imports statement referencing the .xsd and lo and behold I have data!

The intellisense also works, I'm assuming now because it is in the same folder as the class.

So it was the XSD references that were messing it up, although I did absolutely reference the XSD's according to a previous question.

[Use two xsd schemas in visual studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22665287/use-two-xsd-schemas-in-visual-studio-2012)

Points to whoever can see where I went wrong? !!   Yippee its working anyway.  Thanks

Comment: I've now put in 'localTime = returnedXML...<time_zone>...<localTime>.Value' and there is still nothing in there. Damn thing. What else could it be??

Comment: are there credentials required to connect to the weather server?  I get a 403 Forbidden when using the code.  Would rather test things using an actual returned string than a fabricated one.

Comment: @plutonix Surely you can't be suggesting I publish my private key for the API?

Comment: no, I was asking **if** since a) I couldnt see a token being submitted and b) it looks like it might be a free version given the URL.  BTW, no repro using the partial XML snippet and xsd reverse engineered from it.

Answer (score 1):

You must remove the `<data>` element from your query, it is implied since it is the root element.  So it is:

```
   Dim xml = client.DownloadString(...)
   Dim dataNode = XElement.Parse(xml)
   localtime = dataNode...<time_zone>...<localTime>.Value
```

Tested with the xml you posted, works fine.  If this still fails then you didn't get the XML that you expected.  Use the debugger to have a look-see.

Comment: I think the "data" word needs to be in <> no?  It is throwing an "system.data is a namespace.." error when i use your code.   I did try just shortcutting direct to the <localTime> node see above.

Comment: Hmm, are you using the Dim keyword like I showed?  Call it anything you like, I just didn't particularly care for the identifier names you picked.

Comment: My crystal ball says that you have *another* variable named "localtime".  Probably near where ever you declared "callWorldWeatherOnlineSearch".

Comment: There was a property of the class that calls the wwoManager class. I deleted it.  And tried renaming 'Dim localtime1 = dataNode...<time_zone>...<localtime>.Value'.  But your ball must be cloudy today :(